# Are HP laptops generally incompatible with linux?

Tags: drivers, hp

I'm looking to buy a new laptop and find the HP Envy x360 15t a really good laptop in terms of specs and affordability. But, one of my colleagues told me that hp laptops usually have a lot of driver problems with linux. And, I also saw a lot of forums about driver problems with linux on hp laptops.

I don't want to spend too much time banging my head to solve driver problems after buying a laptop (I mean who does?). So, if that's the case I would just buy a Dell (slightly more expensive).

So, I would like to know if any of you guys had (or didn't have) any problems with Linux on your hp laptops. I'm talking any problem from the wifi and touchpad to touchsreen and tablet mode (don't really know if tablet mode's supported on linux).

Comment: One of your colleagues could perhaps be a bit less vague. I'm writing this on an HP laptop that installed perfectly the first time. This site is littered with the travails of folks who have had problems with models from every manufacturer...and answers from folks who successfully installed on models from every manufacturer. Honestly, this seems like a good question to ask your favorite search engine...I tried, and got a pretty clear answer.

Comment: The most common problem with laptops tends to be the wireless card.  doing a quick search it looks like all the laptops with the description you listed (there are at least 4 models I found)- all have this wireless chipset " Intel® 802.11b/g/n/ac (2x2) Wi-Fi® and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo ".  Intel wireless chipset ***usually*** work out of the box with no tweaking.  I can't say these will for sure of course but chances are high that the wireless will work.  I don't see anything else in the specs that screams incompatible, but I'm no expert either.

Comment: TrailRider's right: Intel's drivers are in the kernel.

Comment: Possibly similar x360 13" install info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086

Comment: I recommend broadening your search for the perfect Ubuntu laptop. Many Dell laptop models that don't come with Ubuntu preinstalled have decent product quality, but have compatibility issues with Ubuntu too.

Comment: "Are HP laptops generally incompatible with linux?" No. HP Omen 17" working flawlessly with Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and 19.10. Also installed it on a vivo and 2 others I can't remember the model but also HP. I have no issues with HP (and they have a good trackrecord for Linux esp. their printers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dual booted two HP laptops both were working nicely. The only problem was that Wi-Fi wasn't working at all. For this, I searched online and installed Wi-Fi driver manually (just copy-pasted two commands). Wi-Fi is working fine now.

Yes, this is correct that you find problems with Linux on HP. But these problems are not big; solutions exist already provided by vast open source community. Most of the problems you may get already have been given solutions. This will be a good learning experience to look up for solutions and work upon them. I have Asus FX504. The touchpad wasn't working for which a simple kernel update worked! Now the problem has been resolved and no longer exists in the original kernel.

Remember, if you tend to use Linux then you should be ready to face and lookup for problems and solutions. It's sure that you will face a problem (it may be a minimal) either by updating or something.

Dell PCs are good compatible machines for Linux you can purchase, Hp is also good. You won't face any big problem, in case you face then just lookup for solutions, probably it's would have been answered!

Lastly, any machine can have problems!

Edit: I forgot to mention, there was issue with Dell PC with Ubuntu 18 would boot to black screen. The system comes with 4gb nvidia graphic, i5 intel. I have to install drivers to correct it. After 3-4 hours of continuous work, I was finally able to boot it correctly. The problem wasn't limited to graphics driver. I didn't remember what was it but I worked entire night on that day. 
That PC is working fine today and it has been around 7 months.
Almost majority of the problems now have been solved in Ubuntu 19.

Answer (score 4):

There is a list of Ubuntu-certified machines: For HP and 18.04, the list is [here](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?query=&category=Laptop&level=&release=18.04+LTS&vendors=HP) (which a somewhat smaller list than what you can find for Dell and Lenovo).

This doesn't mean that other HP machines won't work, though, if they use standard chips.